# Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int' but can't find the problem

Tags: python

```
MAX_lINES =5 
MAX_BET = 500
MIN_BET = 1

def deposited_Money():
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("amount seems to be lower than 0. Please increase the amount")
        else:
            print('please enter a number')

    return amount

def get_number_of_lines():
    while True:
        LinesAmount = input("How many lines do you want to bet on? Please choose between 1-" + str(MAX_lINES) + ")?  ")
        if LinesAmount.isdigit():
            LinesAmount = int(LinesAmount)
            if 1 <= LinesAmount <= MAX_lINES:
                break
            else:
                print("please choose a number that is greater than zero and less 6 to begin betting")
        else:
            print("Please choose a real number mate")
    
    return LinesAmount


def get_bet():
     while True:
        amount = input("How much would you like to bet on each line? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if MIN_BET <= amount <= MAX_BET:
                break
            else:
                print(f"Amount must be between. ${MIN_BET} - $ {MAX_BET}")
        else:
            print('please enter a number')

        return amount


def main():
     balance = deposited_Money
     lines = get_number_of_lines()
     while True:
        bet = get_bet()
        total_bet = bet * lines

        if total_bet > balance:
            print(
                f"You do not have enough to bet that amount, your current balance is: ${balance}")
        else:
            break

        print(
        f"You are betting ${total_bet} on {lines} lines. Total bet is equal to: ${total_bet}")

main()
```

I have tried to find out what is causing this problem by looking at the parts of the code where it says it is not a integer but I can't seem to find it. It says there are some problems with line 65 and 54 but I have checked and can't seem to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Your return statement in `get_bet` is inside the while loop, so it always occurs.

Comment: `return amount` shouldn't be inside the loop in `get_bet()`. When it breaks out of the loop, it doesn't execute it.

Comment: @Steve Not quite -- it doesn't execute when the amount is valid and it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, if your function `get_bet()` returns because of the `break`, it will return `None` by default and then cause your error. So deindent `return amount`

Comment: Conversely, when the amount is invalid, it gets returned anyway. So either way, it returns the wrong thing.

Comment: And using `isdigit` is wrong. `"²".isdigit()` is true, but `int("²")` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `get_bet` function:

```py
def get_bet():
     while True:
        amount = input("How much would you like to bet on each line? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if MIN_BET <= amount <= MAX_BET:
                break
            else:
                print(f"Amount must be between. ${MIN_BET} - $ {MAX_BET}")
        else:
            print('please enter a number')

        return amount # <<<
```

The return statement within the function is placed within the loop. By itself it's not a major concern (even if it's generally bad practice), but you also have a `break` if the amount is within your limits. This will cause the loop to break without calling the return statement, and thus causing the `get_bet` function to return nothing, or more specifically, a `None` value. When the program then tries to use that value for `total_bet = bet * lines`, the error you see is thrown because Python doesn't know how to multiply together an integer and `None`.

The fix is to move the return statement outside of the loop so it can return the value when the loop is exited:

```py
def get_bet():
     while True:
        amount = input("How much would you like to bet on each line? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if MIN_BET <= amount <= MAX_BET:
                break
            else:
                print(f"Amount must be between. ${MIN_BET} - $ {MAX_BET}")
        else:
            print('please enter a number')

    return amount
```